# Reference request on Borsuk conjecture

Tags: co.combinatorics, fa.functional-analysis, gt.geometric-topology, discrete-geometry

I just heard of Borsuk conjecture. I want to ask if there are any references preferably looking at the problem from the point of view of Mathematical analysis I can study it from?

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to know about the Borsuk conjecture that is not findable from the links on the Wikipedia page?

Answer (score 2):

You can find a proof of the existence of a counterexample and some references in the *Proofs from THE BOOK* by Aigner and Ziegler.